# Negative sentences understand

Tags: sentence-meaning, negation

How do we understand negative sentences? Are these sentences a negative sentence?

1-It's not what their parents want for them either.

2-There are bright spots of hope though - newcomers such as Michelle Yee Yuan and her husband Alan who gave up office jobs to open a stall not far from Melvin's.

3-They don't take short cuts, so work starts early, shortly after 7am, collecting fresh ingredients, rolling up the rattling metal shutters, then laboriously washing out tubes of pig intestine and fatty strips of pork skin in plenty of cold water.

4-"They said if you are going to eat it, it better be safe, because we don't know where these folks on the street got their supplies from.

5-Don't chop and prepare food on porous wood - surfaces must be stainless steel.

6-"We call that peace of mind. Who doesn't want that?

Comment: The term "negative sentence" is rather vague, but I can't see what possible use it would be to "classify" something like ***Who doesn't want peace of mind?*** as one.Nor do I see the point of you asking us to say whether something like your example #5 (with one negated imperative, and one non-negated) is *on balance* either negative or positive.

Comment: I am sure that in  your own language you have the difference between negative sentences and declarative sentences.....

Comment: There is no such thing as negative sentences in English, as a matter of grammar.

Answer (score 1):

There are many negative constructions in English.  One common negative construction is to add the word "not" to the auxiliary or "be" verb in a clause.

> I am not happy /  I do not like peas / He does not play tennis  / They were not reading. / He has not eaten dinner/  I don't have a pet.

Most of your sentences have at least one negated verb.

The exception is 2) which has a negated adjective "not far"

There are other ways to form negative meanings in English.  You can use words like "nothing" or "nobody" or "no"

> Nobody came to the party / I've had nothing to eat / There are no fish in the lake.

You can also use un- or in- as prefixes of some words

> I'm unhappy.

> It's inedible!

There is no such thing as "negative sentence"  There are clauses that use negation of the verb phrase.  There are phrases that use words like nobody. There are words with an in- or un- prefix, and other forms of negation. A sentence can employ some or many forms of negation. It can have some clauses with negative verbs and some with positive.

Your examples all have several clauses, with some positive verbs and some negative verbs.